# Use new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical from OpenLayers into jQuery

Tags: openlayers-2, filter, jquery

I've a small GIS app, displaying stations on a map. Very simple.
At start, none of the stations are displayed, even if its layer is enabled.
What I want, when I click on a div, is to display one the station according to the OpenLayers.Filter.Logical  method. I plan to use jQuery to do that.
Problem : I don't master jQuery enough.
I'll provide you some codes I made. If you need mor to know, tell me.
My HTML code (extract)

```
</head>
<body onload="init()">
    <div id='banner' style='width: 51%; height: 50px; background-color: #A52A2A; border-top-left-radius: 9px; border-top-right-radius: 9px; text-align: center; font-size: 25px; '>
    <div id="text" style='color: white; font-family: tahoma; line-height:50px;'> Projet</div>
    </div>
    <div id='map' style='width: 51%; height: 500px; float: bottom;'>                                
    </div>
    <div id='button1' style='display: inline-block; margin-top: 1%; width: 10%; height: 50px; background-color: #32CD32; border-radius: 15px;'>
    <div id='txt1' style='text-align: center; font-family: tahoma; color: white; font-size: 25px; line-height: 49px;'>Station 1</div>
    </div>

    <script> 
    $( "#button1" ).click(function() {
        //Put the logical filter there  
    });
    </script>
</body>
```

JS code (extract)

```
station = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("station", {
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
            version: "1.0.0",
            url:  "http://585.182.555.82/sig/geoserver/wfs",
            featureType: "station",
            srsName:"EPSG:2154",
            featureNS: "http://www.obx.com/zodb",
            geometryName: "geom"
        }),
```

Example of a logical filter I already made directly into the station item (working) :

```
filter: new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
            filters: [
                new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
                    type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
                    property: "id_station",
                    value: "2"
                }),
]
        }),
```

You've understood it, my aim is to use the OpenLayers.Filter.Logical into the jQuery function.
I think I have to use something like this : 
station.filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
But I'm not sure how.

If I do

```
<script> // Go jQuery Go !
$( "#button1" ).click(function() {
  alert(station.filter.filters[0].value);
});
</script>
```

It's working (it's returning me "2", as according the logical filter)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using vector layers in OpenLayers, it is always best to use the filter startegy instead of the filter parameter in the layer:

```
var filterStrategy = new OpenLayers.Strategy.Filter({filter: your_filter_here});

var station = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("station", {
    strategies: [ filterStrategy ]
});
```

and:

```
$("#button1").click(function () {
    var filter = new OpenLayers.Filter.Logical({
        type: OpenLayers.Filter.Logical.OR,
        filters: [
        new OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison({
            type: OpenLayers.Filter.Comparison.EQUAL_TO,
            property: "id_station",
            value: 2
        })]
    });
    filterStrategy.setFilter(filter);
});
```

I've built a working example available here:

https://jsfiddle.net/d8f7120x/2/

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll check it out and I'll make a feedback.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment because it's working ! Thanks. And by the way, your example is really nice :-). Anyway, I can't vote up for yoour answer because I don't have enough reputation on the website ;(.

Comment: Thanks for the example. Had some broken external script refs, so I updated it: https://jsfiddle.net/d8f7120x/2/